# Obtener el 25% de los mejores de un listado

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una serie de alumnos, los cuales están nominados a un premio que solo obtendrá el 25% con mejores puntuaciones.

Quiero poner en la tercera columna si el alumno está nominado o no. Para ello, necesito obtener una fórmula que me permita filtrar esos resultados. He intentado aplicar diferentes fórmulas pero no he hallado la correcta. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Dejó aquí una captura de una tabla de ejemplo con su correspondiente [enlace.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7421eGlmkPKmz0IDrL1bKA_AUAP_18_JmwO8TZt4Zc/edit#gid=0)
[image: Tabla]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Dices que has intentado aplicar diferentes fórmulas ¿cuáles son? Si dejas ejemplos de lo que has ido intentando es más fácil orientarte para encontrar la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una solución que he hecho en excel que funciona perfectamente, en la hoja de cálculo de tu enlace. La he probado.

Según tu ejemplo: 
Los datos están desde la celda **C3** hasta **C8**, por lo tanto tenemos una matriz de celdas **C3:C8** (Define la dimensión de tu matriz que necesites)

Luego debemos contar la cantidad de celdas, en tu caso hay: **6**

A continuación calculamos el **25%** de la cantidad de celdas y los **REDONDEAMOS** a un entero, ya que es lo que tenemos, alumnos, no trozos de alumnos. En tu caso saldrían solo **2** de los 6 alumnos.

Posteriormente creamos una **JERARQUIA** con la posición que tiene el peso del valor dentro de la posición de los 6 valores, ordenados de mayor a menor, de forma que el mayor valor sea el 1º

La formula que iría en la columna D en la celda **D3** sería:

```
=SI(JERARQUIA(C3;$C$3:$C$8;0)<=MULTIPLO.SUPERIOR((CONTAR($C$3:$C$8)*25)/100;1);"NOMINADO";"NO")
```

Y en este caso, en **D3** indicaría **NOMINADO**